# Adjusting volume of an <audio> element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

Here's my HTML:

```
<audio id="audio_core" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="audio/bgm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#audio_core').prop('volume', 0.15);
}
```

I want to set the volume lower.

Comment: What do mean by "it won't work"?

Comment: The volume isn't changing

Comment: Are you missing closing `})` at `$(document).ready(function() {})` ? Appears to return expected result at jsfiddle

Comment: Nope, I'm not missing that

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to properly  close `$(document).ready(function()` with `})`, the rest of the code works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#audio_core').prop('volume', 0.15);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio_core" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
 <source src="http://www.maninblack.org/demos/PoliceLineDontCross.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

---

PS: remove `controls="controls"`. Added only to avoid refreshing the page to stop the music.

Comment: Did you run the code snippet ? Sound is enable for your computer/browser ? did you test it on a different computer ?

Comment: @will0956 Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: Yes, I do have jQuery loaded

Comment: I ran it. It is enabled. I don't have another PC to test it on.

Answer (score -2):

Found it. I had to do this:

```
<audio id="audio_core" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="audio/bgm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#audio_core').prop('volume', 0.05);
    })
 </script>
```

Comment: That's exactly the same code you wrote in the question.

Comment: I know. It works when I put it under the audio element.